# Bash - CD into Untared directory with variable URL

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

This is the situation. I have a list of URLs that I need to extract and setup. Its all variable driven, but after I extract, I dont know what my folder will be called. I cant CD into it if I dont know what its called.

```
$DL_DIR = /opt/
$URL = http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.3.3.tar.gz
$FILE=${URL##*/}
$CONFIG = "-- core"

cd "$DL_DIR"
wget $URL
tar xzf $FILE
cd <HOW DO I GO INTO IT?>
./configure "$CONFIG"
make
make install
rm $FILE
```

If this doesnt explain it please say. I really want to get past this problem but Im having a hard time explaining it.

Since I want this to function for any set of URL's which may have two formats like ".tar.gz" or one format ".zip" and may have .'s in the filename like "Python2.3.4" or may not "Nginx", it makes it a bit tricky.

Comment: As an aside, your first four lines are not valid assignments in bash. The left-hand sides should not be prefixed with dollar signs, and no space is allowed around the equals sign. A corrected example: `DLDIR=/opt/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
   #
   # Problem: 
   #  find the path of the "root" folder in an archive
   #
   # Strategy: 
   #  list all folders in the archive.
   #  sort the list to make sure the shortest path is at the top.
   #  print the first line
   # 
   # Weak point:
   #  assumes that tar tf and unzip -l will list files in a certain way
   #  that is: paths ending with / and that the file-list of unzip -l 
   #  is in the fourth column.
   # 

   LIST_FILES=
   FILE=$1
   case ${FILE##*.} in
       gz)
       LIST_FILES="tar tf $FILE"
       ;;
       tgz)
       LIST_FILES="tar tf $FILE"
       ;;
       zip)
       LIST_FILES='unzip -l '$FILE' | awk "{print \$4}"'
       ;;
   esac
   ARCHIVE_ROOT=$(
   echo $LIST_FILES | sh |\
       grep '/$'|\
       sort |\
       head -n1
   )

   # we should have what we need by now, go ahead and extract the files.
   if [ -d "$ARCHIVE_ROOT" ]; then
       cd "$ARCHIVE_ROOT"
   else
       # there is no path (whoever made the archive is a jerk)
       # ...or the script failed (see weak points)
       exit 1
   fi
```

Comment: btw, look at /usr/bin/lesspipe for a good archive detection case ... esac

Answer (score 0):

```
extract_dir=$(tar -tf $FILE | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq)
cd $extract_dir
```

or

```
extract_dir=$(tar -tf $FILE | head -1 | cut -d/ -f1)
cd $extract_dir
```

or

```
ls > .dir_list_1    # save current directory listing as hidden file
tar xzf $FILE       # extract the $FILE
ls > .dir_list_2    # save the directory listing after extraction...
                    # ...as another hidden file
# diff two lists saved in hidden files, this will help you get the created dir
# grep '>' symbol, to get the inserted line
# use head to get the dir in case there are multiple lines (not necessary)
# use cut to remove the '>' and get the actual dir name, store in extract_dir
extract_dir=$(diff .dir_list_1 .dir_list_2 | grep '>' | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2)
# remove temporary files 
rm .dir_list_*
cd $extract_dir
```

Comment: This is where it is tricky. The file format won't always be tar it might be .zip or .tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is going to be exactly one directory in $DL_DIR, then you can use:

```
cd `ls -m1`
```

Another approach would be to loop through the files of the directory:

```
for filename in "$DL_DIR"/*
do
    echo $filename
done;
```

You could perform file tests and other checks as necessary.

Comment: Good idea, but there will be lots in this directory. Could we do it based on time? Copy the name of the newest created folder? Seems like a bad way of doing it though.

Comment: @JamesWillson: In that case, you could loop through the files in $DL_DIR. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, strip the extension of the file with ${FILE##*.} and do the other way around with the directory name using ${FILE%.ext*}:

```
case ${FILE##*.} in
    gz)
    tar xf $FILE
    cd ${FILE%.tar.gz*}
    ;;
    tgz)
    tar xf $FILE
    cd ${FILE%.tgz*}
    ;;
    zip)
    unzip $FILE
    cd ${FILE%.zip*}
    ;;
esac
```

Just one small problem: how do you know if the directory in the archive has the same name af the archive itself?

Comment: You could also use basename for this:
`cd $(basename $FILE)`

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
rm -rf tmpdir
mkdir tmpdir && cd tmpdir || exit
wget "$URL" || exit 1
case "$(ls)" in
  *.tar.gz|*.tgz)
  tar xzf $(ls)
  ;;
  *.zip)
  unzip $(ls)
  ;;
esac
for d in $(ls -d)
do
  ( cd "$d" 2>/dev/null && ./configure && make && make install; )
done
```